# PHP Login Site, sign in without User Info

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, web

I'm working on a website and am having a problem with my PHP login script.  The code lets people sign in through the login button without a username and password. Here's my code:

```
<?php
  $indexPage = true;
  require_once 'libs/Config.php';
  if (secureSession($mysqli) == true) {
    header('Location: dashboard.php');
  }
  if (isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['login'])) {
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT uid, username, password FROM admins WHERE username = ?")) {
      $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['username']);
      $stmt->execute();
      $stmt->store_result();
      $stmt->bind_result($uid, $username, $password);
      $stmt->fetch();
      if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
        if (password_verify($_POST['password'], $password)) {
            $_SESSION['uid'] = $uid;
            $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
            $_SESSION['secure'] = password_hash($password.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
            header('Location: dashboard.php');
            exit;
        } else {
          echo 'Username and password don\'t match.<br/>';
        }
      } else {
        echo 'No user exist with this username.';
      }
    }
  }
?>
```

I'm using a database where the username and password is stored.

How can I fix it so a user will only be signed in with valid username and password?

Comment: Please post your `password_verify` function.

Comment: if (secureSession($mysqli) == true) {
    header('Location: dashboard.php');
  } // think it may be here, hence its always true so you will be taken to dash board, make false and try it see if it still does

Comment: Still nothing worked, anyone know how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

ok then do this

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {   
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT uid, username, password FROM admins WHERE username = '$_POST['username']' and password='$_POST['password']'")) {
      $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['username']);
      $stmt->execute();
      $stmt->store_result();
      $stmt->bind_result($uid, $username, $password);
      $stmt->fetch();
           $_SESSION['uid'] = $uid;
            $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
            $_SESSION['secure'] = password_hash($password.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
            header('Location: dashboard.php');
            exit;
        } else {
          echo 'Username and password don\'t match.<br/>';
        }
      } 
    }
  }
?>
```

Comment: I tried this but this just result that my login page was white.

Comment: can you tell me the exact problem that why login page is white as it should echo something or post your complete code that means your login page(design page) please...i ll try to work on that and will let you within half an hour...

Comment: I dont know, after i added this code the site got white screened.

Answer (score 0):

I normally use mysql as follow. let me know if that helps you

```
<?php
include_once "libs/Config.php"; // hope this file will initialized $con, connection to database
if(isset($_REQUEST['username']))
{
$username=$_REQUEST['username'];
$password=$_REQUEST['password'];

$query= "SELECT * FROM admins WHERE username='".$username."' AND password='".$password."'";
$result=mysql_query($query,$con);
if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0)
{
//sucess
header('Location: dashboard.php'); 
}
else
{
echo 'Username and password don\'t match.<br/>';
}
}
else
{
// form not submitted
}

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to validate user name and password from client side itself before submitting. and try the below code:

```
<?php
      $indexPage = true;
      require_once 'libs/Config.php';
      if (secureSession($mysqli) == true) {
        header('Location: dashboard.php');
      }
      $flag = 1;
      if (isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['login'])) {
        if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT uid, username, password FROM admins WHERE username = ?")) {
          $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['username']);
          $stmt->execute();
          $stmt->store_result();
          $stmt->bind_result($uid, $username, $password);
          $stmt->fetch();
          if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
            if (password_verify($_POST['password'], $password)) {
                $_SESSION['uid'] = $uid;
                $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
                $_SESSION['secure'] = password_hash($password.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
                $flag = 2;
            } else {
                $flag = 3;
            }
          } else {
              $flag = 4;
          }
        }
      }
      switch ($flag) {
          case 2:
              header('Location: dashboard.php'); 
              break;
          case 3:
              echo 'Username and password don\'t match.<br/>';
              break;
          case 4:
              echo 'No user exist with this username.';
              break;
          default :
              // do your default action may be
              echo 'Username and password is required';
      }

    ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! But it didnt work im just getting " Username and password is required " but i still can click login without username and password and getting to the dashboard

Comment: Make the fields required in the html

Comment: This answer goes against several security best practices; for a start, it implies the password is stored in clear in the database without being hashed, which is certainly a very bad idea. Then it also returns too much information, allowing username listing, which is a good start for taking up user accounts just by brute-forcing into it.